# Conditional ISNUMBER Statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to use an ISNUMBER statement but to change the value depending if it was ever true in another row

Take this example:

```
   A.       B.       C 
Device   Status   Results
 dev1.   Trusted   True
 dev1.     -       False
 dev2.     -       False
 dev1.   Trusted   True
 dev3.     -       False
 dev3.   Trusted   True
```

dev1 appears trusted in the first row so the result of the ISNUMBER function appears as True
In the second row, the information is missing so the result appears as False

I would like to be able to find a function stating that as long as a device has been trusted in any row, the result will always be True even if the information is missing

Basically, the previous example would show as:

```
   A.       B.       C 
Device   Status   Results
 dev1.   Trusted   True
 dev1.     -       True
 dev2.     -       False
 dev1.   Trusted   True
 dev3.     -       True
 dev3.   Trusted   True
```

```
C2=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Trusted", B2))
C3=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Trusted", B3))
...
```

I use an ISNUMBER function because I have a string of characters with the word trusted in it, this string can change but if the device is trusted, the word "trusted" will always appear somewhere in the cell.

Comment: As you looking for a Excel Formula, I would post this in AskDifferent instead (as I know you are a Mac OS user :)) -- Otherwise if you want to handle this with AppleScript, you might be able to record column in variable and do a IF statement  but a Excel formula would be easier.

Comment: @Kevin just because one uses Apple equipment does not make it per se an Ask Different question, I have 5 working macs at the moment and used one to work in excel for the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sure this can be reduced, but it works...

You can take each apart to see what is happening.

[image]

Columns F2 and G2 just produce a list of "valid" devices...

Comment: Thank you! This is actually perfect and helps a lot. It is way more complicated that what I thought it would be! This saved me a lot of struggle.

Comment: Then I'm glad it helps, if I figure out an update I will edit the answer.